# How do I test for a mob being attacked?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know what to try. It might be a `/scoreboard` command or a `/testfor` command. I am not sure.

Comment: Have you tried either yet?

Answer (score 1):

A mob's `HurtTime` tag will be set to 10 when struck, decreasing by 1 per tick. You can label mobs with a value of 10 to be those who were struck, and remove the label once it reaches 9 (or a value of 1 if you want to continue targeting that mob during those ticks).

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Creeper] add struck {HurtTime:10s}
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Creeper,tag=struck] remove struck {HurtTime:9s}

/say Creepers recently struck: @e[type=Creeper,tag=struck]
```